# How to set time delay in adding mesh to scene in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to add a mesh into the scene in a time delay . unfortunately `setTimeout` function doesn't work for me

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFF0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
function addMesh(mesh)
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        Scene.add(mesh);
    },3000);
}

for (var i = 0; i < pointzz.length; i += 2) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
    mesh.rotation.z = Math.PI;
    mesh.name = "mesh";
    mesh.position.set(pointzz[i], 0, pointzz[i + 1]);
    mesh.scale.set(15, 15, 15);
    addMesh(mesh);
}
```

here `pointzz` contains the  `x` and `z` coordinates of the `mesh`. The code works fine. All the meshes are added to the `scene` but I need each mesh need to be added in a small time delay

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` works fine in `three.js`.

See **[this fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/tas6enrw/1/)** for a demo (adds mesh and wireframe after 2 seconds).

Why is `setTimout` not what you want? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The meshes are added to the scene without any delay .I want to add each mesh one after a delay then other .

Comment: I updated fiddle. Before only the **wireframe** was added with delay. Now both the **mesh** and the **wireframe** are added with delay.

Comment: I have updated my code can u have a look at it @Wilt

Comment: @ArUn Your code looks fine to me, I improved the formatting a bit. Since you didn't post the `pointzz` coordinates  array I cannot check this part. Is it not working? What is the problem? Any errors in console?

Comment: Do you want to add ( mesh , delay ) or "order" to tineout function? Ie delay == 3000 * ( i + 1 )